# Delete all directiories with specific mask on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I was using svn for versioning my project and then I decided to not use it anymore. But the in every directory of that project is a .svn directory. A few hundreds of them in directory structure. I need to get rid of them with some kind of terminal command. 
I'm sure it would be "rm" but I dont know how to apply a mask and not delete all my files.

Can anyone help me?
I'm running on Mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find <dir_path > -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find working/copy -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} ';'
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
svn export working/copy other/directory
svn export url://repo/ other/directory
```

Export is like checkout, but it does not create .svn directories.